# How To Force Rewrite and Redirect Url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, rewrite

I have a url:

http://domain.com/i.php?c=PT and I Rewrote it to http://domain.com/PT successfully. But When I browse http://domain.com/i.php?c=PT, it wont redirect to http://domain.com/PT. Is there anyway to both redirect and rewrite it?

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])$
RewriteRule ^/index.php$ /%1%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])$  i.php?c=$1$2 [NC,L]
```

Thanks

Update #1: I want to redirect from domain.com/i.php?c=PT -> domain.com/PT.

I don't have index.php file.

Comment: You question is not clear. What I understand is that you succesfully redirected A to B but when you browse A you are not redirected to B. Does it work or not?

Comment: I meant when I browse http://domain.com/PT, it works for me. But when I browse http://domain.com/i.php?c=PT, it keeps the same url instead of redirecting to http://domain.com/PT.

Comment: Ok, so you made a type in your question :) Can you amend it adding also the relevant Apache configuration?

Comment: No, I can't. It is shared hosting.

Comment: There are a lot of Rewrite topics but this is specific.

Comment: Sorry, not clear. Do you need to rewrite `domain.com/PT -> domain.com/i.php?c=PT` or `domain.com/i.php?c=PT -> domain.com/PT`? Are there other URL formats you need to translate? In both cases your rewrite rules are wrong.

Comment: @KevinNguyen It also contains information about how to debug rewrite rules, starting by turning logging on and then reading the logs.

Comment: @ColOfAbRiX I want to rewrite from domain.com/i.php?c=PT -> domain.com/PT.

Comment: The linked question is a
[canonical](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/1986/55514) one. These are
questions where the community has said all it is going to say on a class
of subject, because although everyone's particular problems in that
class are somewhat different, to the extent that they are interesting,
they aren't different, and to the extent that they're different, they
aren't interesting (to anyone save the questioner). So we write one set of 
answers designed to be the last word on the subject, and say no more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what behavior do you want, I see no mention of index.php in your request, but it is in your configuration. Anyway this rewrites any URL from the form `hostname/XX` to `hostname/i.php?c=XX`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z]{2})$  /i.php?c=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

For the opposite translation:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^c=([a-zA-Z]{2})$
RewriteRule ^/i.php$         /%1? [R=301,NC,L]
```

And you can **debug** your rewrite rules adding:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "/tmp/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Comment: To be honest, there is no index.php file. I  redirected index.php.

Comment: These rules didn't work for me. I got 404 when browse domain.com/PT. To make it clear, i want to rewrite domain.com/i.php?c=PT -> domain.com/PT. Whenever people type domain.com/i.php?c=PT -> it will be domain.com/PT on the address bar. Thanks!

Comment: Is `domain.com/PT` a valid URL? Does that resource exists? If it doesn't that's why you get 404. Usually people do the opposite, they translate a human readable URL like `domain.com/articles/myarticle` to `domain.con/articles.php?page=myarticle`

Comment: The resource should be domain.com/i.php?c=PT. And I want to rewrite to domain.com/PT. And when visitors type on their browser domain.com/i.php?c=PT, it will rewrite to domain.com/PT on their address bar. That is my goal.